# Invalid token in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml(update.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sharpUpdate>
   <update appId="CSV_Load">
      <url>ftp://*************/CSV_Load.exe</url>
      <fileName>CSV_Load.exe</fileName>
      <md5>6E0D30994B473CE30ECED6C1C9B8D813</md5>
      <description>Update pokus</description>
      <launchArgs></launchArgs>
   </update>
</sharpUpdate>
```

In program I save this XML to local disk and open:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(file.Name); //open update.xml
                XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//update[@appId=" + appID + ";]");  //appId=CSV_Load
```

but in las row it returns the error:

> contains an invalid token

Do you any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough.What made it work for me was:

```
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//update[@appId='" + appID + "']"); //appId=CSV_Load
```

Make sure you do a couple of checks for not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
string.Format(@"'//update["appId={0}"]'",appID);
```